# Split parent XML element into equivalent number of child element using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to transform an XML and split the main Link element as shown below into equivalent number of child link element: i.e. if link element contains 3 child element I want to have 3 individual link element as shown below

```
<Link>
    <Refrence>abc</Refrence>
    <PoolLink>def</PoolLink>
    <LinkReference>ghi</LinkReference>
</Link>
```

to look exactly like this:

```
<Link>
    <Refrence>abc</Refrence>
</Link>
<Link>
    <PoolLink>def</PoolLink>
</Link>
<Link>
    <LinkReference>ghi</LinkReference>
</Link>
```

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Which XSLT processor exactly do you use? Saxon 9.8 or later or other XSLT 3 processors make that a bit easier than XSLT 2 processors as `snapshot()` or `xsl:copy select="..."` provide ways.

Comment: This is a trivial task even in XSLT 1.0. Where exactly are you stuck with it?

Comment: Show us what you tried. We don't do your homework. We are here to help some one to fix his code.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3 you could use

```
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="Link">
      <xsl:copy-of select="*!snapshot()/.."/>
  </xsl:template>
```